# I Want to print Star pattern

Tags: php

I want to print star pattern like :

[image]
below is my code. but it doesn't work for me. How can i fix this problem.

```
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    for($j=5; $j>$i; $j--){
        echo " ";
    }
    echo "*";
    for($j=1; $j<($i-1)*2; $j++){
        echo " ";
    }
    if($i==1)echo "<br>";
    else echo "*<br>";
}

for($i=4; $i>=1; $i--){
    for($j=5; $j>$i; $j--){
        echo " ";
    }
    echo "*";
    for($j=1; $j<($i-1)*2; $j++){
        echo " ";
    }
    if($i==1)echo "<br>";
    else echo "*<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be okay. just changed `<br>` with `\n`. https://3v4l.org/uXLNM

Comment: if I change \n it print single line  like : * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

Comment: check the link I provided. are you trying to do this in a browser?

Comment: How do the output of this code of yours looks like?

Comment: if you are trying to do this in a browser, just put your code between `<pre></pre>' tag

Comment: Use `&nbsp;` or `&#160;` in place of the space. Multiple consecutive spaces arent rendered in browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put all text that should keep form and not whitespace trimmed in between a `<pre/>` tag

```
<pre><?php
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    for($j=5; $j>$i; $j--){
        echo " ";
    }
    echo "*";
    for($j=1; $j<($i-1)*2; $j++){
        echo " ";
    }
    if($i==1)echo "<br>";
    else echo "*<br>";
}

for($i=4; $i>=1; $i--){
    for($j=5; $j>$i; $j--){
        echo " ";
    }
    echo "*";
    for($j=1; $j<($i-1)*2; $j++){
        echo " ";
    }
    if($i==1)echo "<br>";
    else echo "*<br>";
} ?></pre>
```

Note: if your target is console and PHP-CLI, don't put the `<pre/>` tag, omit the end of PHP tag (`?>`) and replace all `<br/>` tags with `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you guys. I add `<pre>` tag before code and also change `<br>` tag with \n and now it is work. Thanks again. Have a nice day guys..

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
function printPattern($n) 
{ 

$k = 0; 

// Print upper triangle 
for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++)  
{ 

    // Print spaces 
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $n - $i; $j++)  
    { 
        echo " "; 
    } 

    // Print # 
    while ($k != (2 * $i - 1))  
    { 
        if ($k == 0 or $k == 2 * $i - 2) 
            echo "*"; 
        else
            echo " "; 
        $k++; 
    } 
    $k = 0; 

    // move to next row 
    echo "\n"; 
} 
$n--; 

// Print lower triangle 
for ($i = $n; $i >= 1; $i--) 
{ 

    // Print spaces 
    for ($j = 0; $j <= $n - $i; $j++)  
    { 
        echo " "; 
    } 

    // Print # 
    $k = 0; 
    while ($k != (2 * $i - 1))  
    { 
        if ($k == 0 or $k == 2 * $i - 2) 
            echo "*"; 
        else
            echo " "; 
        $k++; 
    } 
    echo "\n"; 
} 
} 

// Driver Code 
$n = 6; 
printPattern($n); 

// This Code is contributed by mits  
?>
```